# intelliJ 14.03 not working with grails

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

We have all had this problem since 6 months, and with serveral updates to intelliJ

We have a medium size grails 2.4.4 project, with 5 exploded plugins. Intellij mostly works OK: we can run and debug the app within intellij, although sometimes it "forgets" a plugin and we have to manually add it back in the F4-> modules menu.

The problem is this:

1. If we select "Syncronize grails settings" Nothing happens.
2. If we right click on the domain classes in the grails view, and do New->Grails Domain class, precisely nothing happens.  No messages, no warnings, no starting any processes, and no domain class.  We have to create ALL our grails classes, including controllers, domains, services etc. on the command line outside intellij.

Needless to say, we have tried a LOT of things to try and fix this, but no luck.

If we start again, wipe the entire project, create a new project, then add back the plugins one by one, generally after the 3rd addition, it starts not working in the manner described above. However, it doesn't matter which 3 we pick - its not the plugin, its intellij cant handle having more than 2, which is untenable.

The problem doesn't exist on the devs with macs, only those with PCs.

Does anyone know how we can debug this, or think of any workarounds we can try?

Comment: i have no idea how to debug something like this. The only thing that i can say is, that we don't have these kind of problems at work. We are using normally 3-7 in-place plugins and it works mostly fine (on Ubuntu 14.04). Do you use in-place plugins or the module feature from intellij?

Comment: I dont have any of these problems either and we have five to six inplace plugins. try to delete the intellij project and create a new one from scratch. remove intellij cache and every thing and try the fresh project

Comment: Maybe it's stupid, but reinstall idea...